# How to add new Device UDID to an existing provisioning profile in the new pattern

Tags: provisioning, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

[image]

I just want to add new device UDID to an existing provisioning profile, to modify the provisioning profile i clicked "Generate" but its showing to download, there is no way to add devices there... please consider my problem respond to me . thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**First add the device udid in devices list by clicking on '+' button in the devices list.  Then, after adding device udid, go to the provisioning profile list. There, select the provisioning profile to which you want to add the device. Afterwards, you get an edit option that you want to use for adding the new UDID, which you previously added to the devices list. You find this option at the bottom.**

[image: Click on edit button]

After clicking edit button we have an option to select device udids

I hope this will help you

**Note**: initially while creating provisioning profile  we have to add atleast one device id else we dont have add device option in edit mode.( If device count is '0' (from screen shot) then we dont option to add devices)

Comment: Where is the devices list you are talking about? Is it on a website, in xcode, or somewhere else?

Comment: @DanielS.its in the website

Comment: @ganeshmanoj Thanks for the description. I have downloaded the new provisioning certificate. Now how can I replace it with the previous one? Should I just double click on it? Or I have to find the old one in keychain access, delete that and install it by double clicking?
Thanks again. :)

Comment: Download new one and just double click on it

Comment: This "Edit" button is now greyed out if the Provisioning Profile is "Managed by Xcode".

Comment: It would not allow me to do so, it says that is managed by Xcode and hence the EDIT button does not show.

Comment: do i need to regenerate the ipa after that?

Comment: @Lakshay ipa for what?

Comment: @ganeshmanoj u ll need to generate new ipa after any changs to the provisioning profile

Answer (score 4):

Go to the devices setting in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action and see how many devices are added in your account after that add the additional devices UDID and save that.

Now when you come back to the provisioning profiles then you will see the devices you just added. You can select all the devices and then press generate. Now you can easily download the updated provisioning profile.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that testers are no longer added via UUID in the new Apple TestFlight.

Test Flight builds now require an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile. The portal does not allow UUIDs to be added to this type of provisioning profile.

Instead, add "Internal Testers" via iTunes Connect:

> Internal testers are iTunes Connect users with the Admin or Technical role. They can be added in Users and Roles.

After adding a user, be sure to click on their name and flip the "Internal Tester" switch.

[image: Internal Tester Toggle Switch]

Then, go to `App > Prerelease > Internal Testers` and invite them to the build.