# How to add iOS device to provisioning profile

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, udid, iphone-6

I currently have 4 iOS devices in my development provisioning profile. Haven't registered a device in months so don't remember how it's done. Yesterday I tried to register iPhone 6 and I couldn't do it.   There's no edit, there's just a delete or download. But I don't know what it'd download because it doesn't specify. I manually added a UDID number to Devices All section but how do i add 5th device to current provisioning profile?

Comment: Quick solution: delete it and make a new one.

Comment: It sounds like you're not an Admin in your portal and are only a Member. Can you please verify your access rights?

Comment: I'm creating the app myself. I signed up to Apple developers myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new Device UDID to an existing provisioning profile in the new pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893863/how-to-add-new-device-udid-to-an-existing-provisioning-profile-in-the-new-patter)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this [How to add new Device UDID to an existing provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15894435/1891327)

Complete help is here [Maintaining Identifiers, Devices, and Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)

Comment: The EDIT button in provisioning profile isn't clickable. Only the Download or Delete button. However, with Download, I don't know what it'll download and i've never clicked download before and I have 4 devices in current provisioning profile registered.

Comment: usully Xcode handles downloading, so never mind. If you can not edit, you do not have enough rights. Ask your admin or agent.  Or you are using Firefox. Try Safari.

Comment: What you mean I don't have enough rights. I'm creating the app myself. I signed everything. I'm using Safari. I never had an issue with adding device to provisioning profile so I really don't know why it's not letting me now.

Comment: Try creating a new profile. Sometimes it helps clearing the browser completely and trying again.

Comment: Does creating a new profile delete the other 4 devices that  I currently use for testing?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Devices are added separately. 
You add devices to the portal. You created a developer certificate. 
Then you create a provisioning profile which has information for devices and developer certificates.