# Where I need to put UDID info in diawi?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, diawi

I need to create the diawi link for current UDID. So I have build and have archived the project in xcode -> then export -> have saved Ad Hoc Deployment -> a few next and finally i have gotten .ipa file.

Then I go to the diawi.com and send add `.ipa` file and send. And now I get a link to the webapp.diawi.com where I can see the link for download the app but I am totally don't understand where I need to put current UDID.

When I am uploading .ipa file in diawi.com there no place where I can put this one.

Comment: refer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893863/how-to-add-new-device-udid-to-an-existing-provisioning-profile-in-the-new-patter.Hope this will help you.

Comment: @sergs you can see the all UDID which you added with provisional profile in diawi website of your app.its also gives you additional info about your apps.But it will be valid upto 7 days only for free account after that you should upload again.25 installations per app.Max 250MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put the UDID in diawi. Only those devices whose UDID is added to the provisioning profile with which you have archived the app can install the app from that diawi link.

Comment: So this UDID i need to add in provisioning profile?

Comment: Yup you need to add UDID's of all the devices on which you need to install the app in the provisioning profile.

Comment: @AravindAR. One question. I have released a build on diawi with say 10 UDID's. Now I want to add another device, I do that from the apple developer portal. Do i now have to create and upload a new build to diawi or will the new testers be able to install it from the old link ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all UUID's in Provisioning Profile(on apple developer portal).
Import that profile in Xcode and then create and upload the new ipa or zip in diawi.
No need to add any UUID's in diawi.