# How to add devices to provisioning profile for sharing to Diawi

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-provisioning

I need to archive a build of my iOS app for distribution on Diawi.
I need to add the UDIDs of the testers to my provisioning profile first and I am afraid of messing up the current provisioning profile which are working for the app.

First I just want to check if these steps are still valid for what I would like to do:

> First add the device udid in devices list by clicking on '+' button
>   in the devices list.
>
> Then, after adding device udid, go to the provisioning profile list.
>   There, select the provisioning profile to which you want to add the
>   device.
>
> Afterwards, you get an edit option that you want to use for adding the
>   new UDID, which you previously added to the devices list. You find
>   this option at the bottom.

I found these steps at this answer (2013) but I think they may have been when Apple were still adding devices with UDIDs (whereas now it is done via apple ID (email): [How to add new Device UDID to an existing provisioning profile in the new pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893863/how-to-add-new-device-udid-to-an-existing-provisioning-profile-in-the-new-patter/15894435#15894435)

Secondly, after I click add device in my apple developer account, they are asking for the device name. I only have the UDID of the testers phones - do I need their phones name also?

Comment: You can give any name to that device , its just for identify device for later which one relates to whom. you will get device model automatically.

Comment: Thanks Nauman. Do you know if it is safe to do this for uploading my app to another provider like Diawi? Does Apple prohibit it for non apple developers? Most of the testers will not be developers.

Comment: Diawi is just distribution server and it is save. after uploading you got the Link from Diawi from where tester can download. `TestFlight` is another option for testing.

Comment: Do I need to create an ad hoc distribution profile for it? At the moment it doesn't have that.

Comment: No need of Ad hoc Distribution profile. Just  export for `Development` and upload that iPA on Diawi.

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks a lot for your help! Oh yeah, do I need to import the new updated provisioning profile into Xcode?

Comment: Yes, definitely.